# Quicksort using a binary file of ints with duplicates. Having trouble with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, binaryfiles, quicksort

**First off, I want to state that this is homework.**

Often times we'll have assignments that I'll post questions for after we've finished it and I'd like to continue working with it to improve my ability, but in this case I'm just stumped!

We have been tasked with implementing a quicksort using a binary file, using only the file.seek , file.read and file.write commands. This is a binary file of integers.

The problem I am having is the recursion part, calling the function on the "subtrees" of the pivot. I have been following the algorithm put forth on this website: http://xoax.net/comp_sci/crs/algorithms/lessons/Lesson4/ and have been using the code example as a pseudo-code for my binary file implementation.

Here's my code:

```
//Algorithm and code example used:
void manage( fstream & file , int lindex , int fSize ){


    //Chunks of 1 or 0 do not need sorting
    if( fSize <= 1 )
        return;

    //Choose point in file as "pivot." Pivot is a value.
    //pp is the index of "pivot"
    int pp = (rand() % fSize) + lindex;
    file.seekp( pp * sizeof( int ) , file.beg );
    int pivot;
    file.read( (char*)&pivot , sizeof( int ) );

    //Choose "indices" to be swapped. These will be used in seekp
    int leftIndex = lindex;
    int rightIndex = fSize - 1;

    //Swap val , swap val, temp storage, swap index 1 , swap index 2
    int leftSwap , rightSwap , temp , tempI1 , tempI2 = 0;

    //Dummy indecies to help with tracking partitions.
    int dumL = leftIndex;
    int dumR = rightIndex;

    while( dumL < dumR ){

        //Move to left index from the file beginning.
        file.seekp( dumL * sizeof( int ) , file.beg );

        do{

            tempI1 = file.tellp() / sizeof( int );
            dumL = tempI1;
            file.read( (char*)&temp , sizeof( int ) );
        }

        while( temp < pivot );

        leftSwap = temp;

        //Move to right index.
        file.seekp( dumR * sizeof( int ) , file.beg );
        int n = 1;

        do{

            tempI2 = file.tellp() / sizeof( int );
            dumR = tempI2;
            file.read( (char*)&temp , sizeof( int ) );
            file.seekp( ( rightIndex - n ) * sizeof( int ) , file.beg );
            n++;
        }           

        while( temp > pivot );

        rightSwap = temp;

        //Swap values
        int hold = 0;

        if( leftSwap == rightSwap && rightSwap == pivot )
            break;

        file.seekp( tempI1 * sizeof( int ) , file.beg );
        file.read( (char*)&hold , sizeof( int ) );

        file.seekp( tempI1 * sizeof( int ) , file.beg );
        file.write( (char*)&rightSwap , sizeof( int ) );

        file.seekp( tempI2 * sizeof( int ) , file.beg );
        file.write( (char*)&leftSwap , sizeof( int ) );
    }

    cout << "pp: " << pp << endl;
    cout << "dumL: " << dumL << endl;
    cout << "dumR: " << dumR << endl << endl;

    //cout << "Lmanage: \n\t Lindex: 0\n\tSize: " << dumL << endl;
    manage( file , 0 , dumL );
    //cout << "Rmanage: \n\t Lindex: " << dumL + 1 << "\n\tSize: " << fSize - dumL - 1 << endl;
    manage( file , dumL + 1 , fSize - (dumL - leftIndex) - 1 );
}


void quicksort( fstream & file , int iSize ){

    srand( ( unsigned int ) time( 0 ) );
    manage( file , 0 , iSize );
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){

    if( argc != 2 ){

        cout << "Invalid number of arguments.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    fstream file;
    int x = 0;

    file.open( argv[1] , ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in );

    //Calculate number of ints in file.
    file.seekg( 0 , file.end );
    int size = file.tellg() / sizeof( int );

    cout << "size: " << size << endl;

    quicksort( file , size );

    return 0;
}
```

"arg" is a binary file containing 100 integers, with possible duplicates. The issue is that it seems to sort the first 1/4th but the indexing gets mixed up and the "size" argument goes negative.

---

**Edit: Added my main and updated with changes from comments.**

Comment: For starters, stop seeding your RNG with each recursion layer. `srand()` should be in your program startup; nowhere else. Second, a common mistake made in quick sort implementations is failure to SKIP the pivot slot once it has been placed when recursing into the sub-sequences. Look at your code *very* carefully to ensure you're not making that same mistake. The pivot should not be included in *either* of the subsequences being recursed.

Comment: Also, don't pass a filename into `manage()`; pass an open `fstream` reference. You don't need all those file handles open, and you're bound to have issues with sharing.

Comment: I thought to do that, and did initially, but I ended up getting a big error I did not understand. I assumed that I was not allowed to pass open files as an argument.

Comment: You probably tried to pass it (the stream) byvalue rather than by-reference. By-value C++ stream parameters are not allowed; the copy-constructor is private (for good reason if you think about it).

Comment: That was it, my signature was "fstream arg" not "fstream& arg"

Comment: Why not read the file into memory, sort it, then write it back out?

Comment: @brianbeuning The goal of the project is to sort it in the file rather than the memory

Comment: @joshua Every file.seek is a disk seek, so for a big (20 GB) file this would be very slow.  One way to sort a big file is to load pieces (say 1 GB) that will fit into memory, and sort them, then write the result to a temp file.  When all pieces are sorted, then merge all the temp files into one result file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize an in-place qsort algorithm may not be a popular choice, but it makes this specific instance much more understandable. See the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

static void quicksort_stream(std::iostream& st,
                             std::ios::off_type left,  // inclusive
                             std::ios::off_type right, // exclusive
                             unsigned int indent=0)
{
    std::ios::off_type len = (right - left);
    if (len <= 1)
        return;

    // an interesting way of looking at the sort.
    std::string sIndent(indent,' ');
    cerr << sIndent << left << ',' << right << endl;

    // choose a random pivot index form our range:
    std::ios::off_type pivot_idx = left + std::rand() % (len-1);

    // get the pivot value, then swap the *last* value in our
    //  range into the pivot slot. it will be putting the pivot
    //  value in when were done.
    int pivot = 0, val = 0;
    st.seekg(pivot_idx * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
    st.read((char*)&pivot, sizeof(int));
    st.seekg((right-1) * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
    st.read((char*)&val, sizeof(int));
    st.seekg(pivot_idx * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
    st.write((char*)&val, sizeof(int));

    // now start the partition scan.
    pivot_idx = left;
    for (std::ios::off_type i=left; i<(right-1);++i)
    {
        st.seekg(i * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
        st.read((char*)&val, sizeof(int));
        if (val < pivot)
        {
            // swap the current selection with whatever is at
            //  the curent pivot index.
            int val2 = 0;
            st.seekg(pivot_idx * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
            st.read((char*)&val2, sizeof(int));
            st.seekg(i * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
            st.write((char*)&val2, sizeof(int));
            st.seekg(pivot_idx * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
            st.write((char*)&val, sizeof(int));
            ++pivot_idx;
        }
    }

    // store the pivot value back at the pivot index,
    //  placing that value in the last slot of the partition.
    st.seekg(pivot_idx * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
    st.read((char*)&val, sizeof(int));
    st.seekg((right-1) * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
    st.write((char*)&val, sizeof(int));
    st.seekg(pivot_idx * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
    st.write((char*)&pivot, sizeof(int));

    // and finally,invoke on subsequences. skipping the pivot index
    quicksort_stream(st, left, pivot_idx, indent+1);
    quicksort_stream(st, pivot_idx+1, right, indent+1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // create a vector of 100 random int values in [1,1000]
    std::vector<int> vals;

    // build generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rgen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 999);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vals), 100, [&dist,&rgen](){ return dist(rgen); });

    // open the output file and dump this to that location.
    std::fstream fs(argv[1], ios::out|ios::binary);
    fs.write((const char*)vals.data(), vals.size() * sizeof(vals[0]));
    fs.flush();
    fs.close();

    // now open the stream and sort it
    fs.open(argv[1], ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    quicksort_stream(fs, 0, 100);
    fs.flush();
    fs.close();

    // clear the content of the exiting vector.
    std::fill(vals.begin(), vals.end(), 0);
    fs.open(argv[1], ios::in|ios::binary);
    fs.read((char *)vals.data(), vals.size() * sizeof(vals[0]));
    cout << endl << "Sorted" << endl;
    std::copy(vals.begin(), vals.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

I've included a recursive indented 'print' mechanism in this to demonstrate the nature of quicksort and how it works. The output of a sample run appears below. I hope it helps you out.

**Sample Output**

```
0,100
 0,66
  2,66
   2,23
    2,20
     2,5
     6,20
      6,15
       6,11
        7,11
         9,11
       12,15
        12,14
      16,20
       17,20
        17,19
    21,23
   24,66
    24,62
     24,44
      24,29
       24,26
       27,29
      30,44
       30,42
        30,32
        33,42
         33,39
          33,37
           33,35
         40,42
     45,62
      45,60
       46,60
        46,52
         46,48
         49,52
          50,52
        53,60
         53,59
          53,57
           55,57
    63,66
 67,100
  67,72
   67,69
   70,72
  73,100
   73,94
    73,85
     73,80
      73,75
      76,80
       76,78
     81,85
      81,84
       82,84
    86,94
     86,89
     90,94
      90,92
   95,100
    95,99
     97,99

Sorted
3
8
23
27
40
54
68
78
90
97
118
120
127
130
139
149
153
155
158
168
201
210
221
235
240
241
247
260
271
274
285
292
311
317
325
327
330
332
334
362
371
410
415
427
444
478
481
487
492
499
499
513
540
542
543
543
556
567
575
578
621
624
634
634
635
661
676
676
690
693
694
706
739
777
780
793
793
798
822
834
835
836
836
850
865
871
883
884
900
903
907
917
924
924
935
943
945
946
983
996
```

Comment: Wow that was -way- more than I was looking for. Thanks a bunch. Hopefully I can figure out what I was doing incorrectly with this.

Comment: @Joshua Its just a different sub-algorithm of quicksort, The double-ended approach does buy you one attribute the single does not. It swaps two elements known to be in opposite sequences rather than relocating one at a time as needed. Ultimately, the O(nlogn) is still the same, just *potentially* less movement. As I said, I prefer this algorithm only because it is much easier to understand, especially when teaching people about quicksort. Hopefully you agree.